# using Java object refs for inter-thread communication utilizing synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, visibility, memory-barriers

Consider the following example:

Thread 1:

```
data.a = 1;
synchronized (sth) {
    shared = data;
}
```

Thread 2:

```
synchronized (sth) {
    assertEquals(1, shared.a);
}
```

Assume that the code in Thread 2 gets executed after the code for Thread 1.

Is the assert guaranteed to succeed, ie. does the memory barrier inherent to the lock release in thread #1 extend to the assignment of the value 1 before and outside of the synchronized block?

Comment: Didn't you ask [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913091/using-java-object-refs-for-inter-thread-communication-utilizing-synchronized-blo?noredirect=1#comment69038424_40913091) just a short while ago?

Comment: I removed the notify/wait stuff because it made ppl think about the wrong question and deleted the previous question.

Comment: Yes. Also true without `synchronized` if `shared` is `volatile`

Comment: Only if that assumption holds. But you can't guarantee that it will. You might have `data.a = 1;` execute in `Thread 1`, then `synchronized(sth)` and `assert` in `Thread 2`, failing. Then `synchronized(sth)` and the assignment in `Thread 1`.